# CSS Multiple background Images

Tags: html, css

In CSS we can give multiple background images to a div by specifying

```
background-image: url(img_flwr.gif), url(paper.gif);
```

Will all the images specified here will load? Or if first image is not available, then the second image will load? If all the images will get loaded, isn't it affect the loading time of the website?

Comment: Hm, you could test such a simple thing on your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The different background images are separated by commas, and the images are stacked on top of each other, where the first image is closest to the viewer.

You can read more on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds)

Answer (score 2):

Both images are loaded together. It doesn't work like a fallback:

```css
body {
background: url('http://via.placeholder.com/350x150') no-repeat, url('http://via.placeholder.com/150x150');
}
```

The affect on loading time will come down to the size of the images being used.